# Pandas Lambda function not working as I would like

Tags: pandas, lambda

I have a data frame, but the headings can change dynamically, as such I am using i.loc for Columns 4 onwards.

My working code is:

```
cv.iloc[:,[4]] = cv['Allocation'].apply(lambda x: x if dt.strptime(dates[0], "%Y-%m-%d") <= dt.strptime('2021-12-31', "%Y-%m-%d") else 0)
```

This applies the contents of cv['Allocation'] if the first date in my list is <= the fixed date in the formula.

However, what i would like to do is swap the fixed date for a Panda Column
I want this:

```
cv.iloc[:,[4]] = cv['Allocation'].apply(lambda x: x if dt.strptime(dates[0], "%Y-%m-%d") <= cv['Allocation Completion Date'] else 0)
```

If I do that, I get:
*'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: Not really, as I am not using AND or OR, I kinda get the concept, but I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I adjusted from the link you posted:
```
cv.iloc[:,[4]] = cv['Allocation'].apply(lambda x: dt.strptime(dates[0], "%Y-%m-%d") <= cv['Allocation Completion Date']) | 0
```
now i just get NaNs ... lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dt.strptime(dates[0], "%Y-%m-%d") <= cv['Allocation Completion Date']` return a Series of bool.

so, try `np.where`:

```py
cond = dt.strptime(dates[0], format="%Y-%m-%d")  <= cv['Allocation Completion Date']
cv.iloc[:,[4]] = np.where(cond, cv['Allocation'], 0)
```

Comment: np.where, I feel like an idiot now, you know when you get lost in the code, wood for trees style.. thank you so much.